# Open Firefox menu with keyboard

Tags: firefox, keyboard

How do I open the Firefox menu using the keyboard? (I mean the one at the top left corner)

Windows XP.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Which menu are you attempting to open? (On Windows at least there are two possibilities in the "top left corner".)

Comment: The menu that says Firefox on it.

Comment: Alt-Enter/Alt-F opens the File menu, Alt-Space opens the Windows menu. [Wikipedia has a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts) of common Windows shortcuts, and this list turned up as the first result from a naive search. . .

Comment: @JonathanGarber Did you even bother checking whether the solution works before writing it?

Comment: I don't have the Big Orange Button in my personal version of Firefox because it's useless clutter. You're correct in that I didn't try the same thing you were trying. My apologies. That being said, now that I understand to what you're referring, a search for "firefox button keyboard shortcut" turns up the answer in the top results. Easwee has one of the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=575279) bug report you cant for now, but they are planning to use alt+f in the future.

> Alex Faaborg [:faaborg] (Firefox UX) 2011-10-06 14:12:47 PDT
>
> We are going to use alt-f, it's just slightly more complex since it is
>   overloaded with multile behaviors:
>
> downclick on alt-f: display the firefox menu alt upclick (no f):
>   display the traditional menu bar alt upclick, followed by f downclick:
>   display the file menu in the traditional menu bar

Comment: This is now https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1259818